# Angular & Json for a single page application

Tags: angularjs, json, scope

For a project we have to make a single page application with 1 controller. We are accessing a server and this is all we have been given as an example:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.target = 'targetURL';
    $scope.clickFunction = function() {
      $http.get($scope.target)
          .then(function successCall(response) { 

          }, function errorCall() {

          }
        );  
    };
});
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to display the data that has been retrieved

Comment: is `successCall()` defined somewhere else? If not, you could try something like `$http.get($scope.target).then(data => console.log(data))` That will show you the "shape" of the data. Then you can bind that data to the UI, which will involve learning a little Angular... Also, what version of Angular is this? It looks like Angular 1?

Comment: @duhaime if $scope variable exist in Angular world this is Angular1